# Substring in string

Tags: ruby

This function should take in two strings "daBcD" and "ABC". It is trying to create the string "b" from the letters in "a". You can only delete or capitalize letters, you cant change them. b will always contain all uppercase letters.

```
def abbreviation(a, b)
aArray = a.split('')
idx = 0
aArray.each do |char|
    #print "char: #{char}\n"
    #print "Before loops: #{aArray}\n"
    if char.casecmp(b[idx]) == 0
        char.upcase!
        idx += 1
        #print "char: #{char}\nArry: #{aArray}\n"
        #print "idx: #{idx}\n siz: #{b.size}\n"
        if idx == b.size
            aArray.reject! {|i| i == 'delete'}
            aArray.slice!(b.size)
            break
          end
    else
      aArray[aArray.index(char)] = 'delete'
      #print "deleted, now is: #{aArray}\n"
    end
  end
  res = aArray.join('')
  if res == b
    return 'YES'
  else
    return 'NO'
  end
end
```

This works for a couple test cases, but fails most of them. Can someone describe a better approach?

Comment: I don't think your description is accurate--there are more restrictions than you've mentioned. Here's the problem link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/abbr/problem

Comment: If this is indeed the problem referred to by @ggorlen, I suggest you give up on it, as the setter of the problem believes, mistakenly, that it can be formulated as a dynamic programming problem and therefore is solvable in reasonable time for `a` having up to 1,000 characters. I just left a comment at the hackerrank stie that explains why dynamic programming cannot be used here and gave an example where the setter's proposed approach to solving it has a computation complexity of O(2^`n`), where `n = a.size`.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed the problem is to determine whether the characters in `b` appear in `a` (case indifferent), in the same order as in `b`, but not necessarily contiguous in `a` (see the second example below). If they do I return an array of the indices at which they appear in `a`. If there is no match, `nil` is returned.

```
def doit(a, b)
  m = a.match(Regexp.new(b.each_char.map { |c| "(#{c})" }.join('.*'),
                         Regexp::IGNORECASE))
  return nil if m.nil?
  (1..b.size).map { |i| m.begin(i) }
end

doit "daBcD", "ABC"
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
doit "daXBDecf", "ABC"
  #=> [1, 3, 6]
doit "dacBD", "ABC"
  #=> nil
```

For the first example the regular expression is as follows.

```
Regexp.new("ABC".each_char.map { |c| "(#{c})" }.join('.*'), Regexp::IGNORECASE)
  #=> /(A).*(B).*(C)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolutely easiest way is via regular expression:

```
def abbreviation(a, b)
  re = Regexp.new(b.each_char.map(&Regexp.method(:quote)).join('.*'), Regexp::IGNORECASE)
  !!re.match(a)
end

abbreviation("daBcD", "ABC")
# => true
abbreviation("daCbD", "ABC")
# => false
```

For the input `ABC`, we'll construct a regular expression `/A.*B.*C/i`, then test the other string against it. The `.*` construct will account for "deletion"; the `IGNORECASE` option for "capitalisation".

EDIT: If the problem is further constrained that only lowercase letters can be deleted, as suggested by the comments,

```
def abbreviation(a, b)
  # (b is uppercase only)
  re_pat = b.each_char.map { |c| "[#{c}#{c.downcase}]"}.join('[[:lower:]]*')
  re = Regexp.new(re_pat)
  !!re.match(a)
end

p abbreviation("daBcD", "ABC") # => true
p abbreviation("daBdcD", "ABC") # => true
p abbreviation("daBDcD", "ABC") # => false
```

Comment: I see my answer is very similar to your (earlier) answer. The only real difference is that I report the locations of the letters of `b` in `a`. In view of the example it may be that the OP is only concerned about the case where `b` is a substring of `a`. I suspect we both rejected that interpretation because it is a less interesting question!

Comment: @CarySwoveland: No, we both rejected it because OP explicitly mentioned deletion of characters as a possibility :)

Comment: Ah, yes. I guess I had it right the first time around. See the link given by @ggorlen in a comment on the question. If that’s the problem it appears more complex than we thought, as capital letters cannot be deleted and both `a` and `b` may have duplicate letters